# How to program a transponder key of a 2000 Toyota Sienna

Tags: sienna, ignition-key, immobilizer

This is a follow-up question to my [previous question regarding the replacement of the ignition switch cylinder](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/9003/replacing-the-ignition-switch-tumbler-cylinder) in my car.

In my 2000 Sienna there is an immobilizer circuit embedded in the switch. I need to replace the tumbler part, but a replacement key has to be programmed with the immobilizer code.

I found online the instruction for how to program a blank transponder key for Siennas of later models, but could not find the particular sequence of actions for the 2000 XLE.

Any idea where I can find it, before I order the $140 part?

---

**UPDATE:** As expected from finding the procedure of later Sienna's and other Toyota cars, there is a simple procedure for registering keys on the 2000 model that does not require a shop Scan Tool (something like open and close the door 5 times, press the brake paddle 6 times, etc.). Unfortunately, I could not find it with online search. Fortunately, a very nice local mechanic was able to print out the procedure, that he found in a subscription based forum site, and gave it to me for free... Out of courtesy to his generosity, I cannot post it here.

<sub>This is not really an answer, so I just updated the question with the latest info.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the method if you don't have a scan tool. Note this is for a brand new key & ECM.

Ensure SECURITY indicator light is flashing. SECURITY indicator is located on left side of instrument panel.

Insert ignition key into ignition lock cylinder. Note that SECURITY indicator light should now remain on steady.

Once ignition key registration is under way, SECURITY indicator light should turn off. After ignition key registration is complete, SECURITY indicator light should come on steady. Remove ignition key.

If the registration was complete and system is operating normally when ignition key was removed from ignition lock cylinder, the SECURITY indicator light should flash. If ignition key registration was not completed with Engine Control Module (ECM) in automatic registration mode, a code 2-1 will be displayed by SECURITY indicator light. When inserting an already registered ignition key, a code 2-2 will be displayed by SECURITY indicator light.

If programming additional ignition keys, repeat process starting with step 1. If additional ignition keys do not need programming, procedure is complete. SECURITY indicator light should go off once last ignition key (sub-key) is registered.

To complete automatic registration mode, depress and release brake pedal at least 5 times within 15 seconds, or request automatic registration mode completion by using Toyota scan tool connected to Data Link Connector (DLC) No. 3.

[image]

Also when you want to add an additional master key

Insert registered master key into ignition lock cylinder. Within 15 seconds of inserting master key into ignition lock cylinder, depress and release accelerator pedal 5 times.

Within 20 seconds of depressing and releasing accelerator pedal, depress and release brake pedal 6 times. Remove master key from ignition lock cylinder.

Within 10 seconds of removing master key from ignition lock cylinder, insert master key to be registered in ignition lock cylinder.

Within 10 seconds of inserting master key to be registered in ignition lock cylinder, depress and release accelerator pedal one time. Ensure SECURITY indicator light flashes. SECURITY indicator is located on left side of instrument panel.

After one minute, additional master key should be registered. SECURITY indicator light should turn off.

If registering additional master keys, repeat process starting with step 3 within 10 seconds. The registration mode is complete after removing master key from ignition lock cylinder within 10 seconds and brake pedal is depressed or SECURITY indicator has turned off for at least 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. It has been a long time since I replaced my 2000 Sienna, so I cannot verify the information. However, when I did it, I really did not need a scan tool for that. It is just the 2nd part of your post that applied.

Comment: Does this work for Honda Fit 2009? I need to add a new key for it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a factory or equivalent scan tool to program the new key.

Comment: Thanks. I have a scan tool, but I don't think it shows me any relevant info. I know that for other Toyota cars, or later Sienna models, the programming is pretty easy and does not require any tool except for the original key. I am looking for such algorithm for my car.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy way to add a new key to the computer, as designed by the manufacturer.  This information has been taken from [this site](https://northcoastkeyless.com/2000-toyota-sienna-keyless-entry-remote-programming-instructions/) -- all credit there.

> 1. Start with key out of the ignition, drivers door is open all others closed and drivers door is unlocked.
> 2. Insert key into ignition (Do not turn) and pull it out.
> 3. Perform these steps within 40 seconds:
>
>    1. Using the power door lock switch on drivers door perform 5
>         lock/unlock cycles starting with lock. Use an even pace and try to
>         go about one cycle per second. **(1 cycle = 1 lock and 1 unlock.)**
>    2. Close, then open drivers door.
> 4. Perform these steps within 40 seconds:
>
>    1. Using the power door lock switch on drivers door perform 5
>         lock/unlock cycles starting with lock. Use an even pace and try to
>         go about one cycle per second.
>             **(1 cycle = 1 lock and 1 unlock.)**
>    2. Insert the key in the ignition cylinder.
>    3. Turn the ignition to ON (Do NOT Start) then back to OFF.
>    4. Turn the ignition to ON (Do NOT Start) then back to OFF.
>    5. Remove the key from the ignition.
> 5. Within 3 seconds the power door locks should cycle automatically indicating successful entry into programming mode. Return to step 1 if the locks do not cycle at this point.
> 6. Perform these steps within 40 seconds:
>
>    1. Press the lock and unlock buttons on the remote simultaneously for 1 second.
>    2. Immediately after letting go of the lock and unlock buttons, Press the lock button by itself and hold for 2 seconds. Within 3 seconds the door locks should cycle once indicating successful programming. If the door locks don’t cycle or cycle twice, repeat sub-steps 1 and 2; your remote has not been accepted.
>    3. Repeat sub-steps 1 and 2 in step 6 for each new transmitter.
> 7. Close driver door. Test all remotes. Programming is complete.
>
> <sub>https://northcoastkeyless.com/2000-toyota-sienna-keyless-entry-remote-programming-instructions/</sub>

Answer (score 0):

That only works if you have a master key,if you dont have a master key you need to flash the computer to register new keys.

Answer (score 0):

How to Program 2000 Renault Megane All Keys Lost 
Renault [Auto Key Programmer](http://www.cnautotool.com/category-8-b0-Auto+key+Programmer.html) guide can be divided into 4 types according to car model year:

**Pre-2016:** Straight key, 60 chip.. Add key by CN900 Mini key copy machine.  Read BCM data and write key when all keys lost.

**2006-2010:** Smart card, ID46 chip. Read IMMO code with X300 key programmer then program key via OBD directly.

**2010-2012:** Smart card, 46 chip. Part of them can be done by SKP900, X300 via OBD.

**2012-2015:** cannot program via OBD. Require to read BCM dump and write key, can start car and use remote control.

Here is an example of Renault Megane 2000 year key programming under all key lost situation.

**Step 1:**

Disassemble BCM computer

Open BCM, locate CPU 1K20C chip MC68HC705B16

Desolder the CPU chip to XPROG Programmer. Read data and then save it.

**Step 2:** Write Key

Use Tango or TM100 Programmer to write key (here we use TM100)

Selecy KeyMaker->Renault->Megane->2000

Click on “Open Dump File” to upload CPU 1K20C dump data just read.

TM100 key programmer will show original key number and immobilizer information
22-8

Select key position to be programmed. Place a 60 chip into TM100’s coil, click on Write Key

TM100 software will write 60 chip data to CPU and generate new file

Rewrite new file back to CPU (MC68HC705B16), reinstall BCM to car.

Now you can start car with the new programmed key.

Comment: Thanks @user32556 and welcome to the forum. I am not sure how your answer (regarding a Renault Megane) is related to my question?