# 2000 Toyota Sienna had new keys done at dealership now van wont crank and security light keeps flashing

Tags: toyota, sienna

2000 Toyota Sienna had new keys made, now it won't crank. The security light keeps flashing.

Comment: Hi Connie!  Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  Does the key turn in the ignition, or was it cut wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The 2000 Sienna had transponder-equipped keys. If the security light is flashing, it's likely the dealership did not pair the new transponder key with your vehicle, or did not do it properly. Many vehicles allow the user to program keys themselves. Check your owner's manual for instructions.

Comment: See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/58238/12770 for programming instructions.

Comment: If you paid them to do it, them get them to sort it out...